# Control array calculator in VB6

Tags: arrays, vb6

In my computing class we have been working on using control arrays to create a basic calculator. Keep in mind I've never worked with control arrays before.
This is the code I currently have:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CmdCalc_Click(Index As Integer)
    Dim TempSave1 As Double
    Dim Answer As Double
    Dim Symbol As String
    Dim TempSave2 As Double

    If CmdCalc(Index) = 10 Then
        TempSave1 = LblOutput.Caption
        Symbol = "/"
    ElseIf CmdCalc(Index) = 11 Then
        TempSave1 = LblOutput.Caption
        Symbol = "*"
    ElseIf CmdCalc(Index) = 12 Then
        TempSave1 = LblOutput.Caption
        Symbol = "-"
    ElseIf CmdCalc(Index) = 14 Then
        TempSave1 = LblOutput.Caption
        Symbol = "+"
    End If

    LblOutput.Caption = ""

    If Index = 13 Then
        TempSave2 = LblOutput.Caption
        Answer = TempSave1 & Symbol & TempSave2
    End If

    If Index = 0 Or 1 Or 2 Or 3 Or 4 Or 5 Or 6 Or 7 Or 8 Or 9 Or 10 Or 11 Or 12 Or 14 Then
        LblOutput.Caption = LblOutput.Caption & CmdCalc(Index).Caption
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub CmdClear_Click()
    LblOutput.Caption = ""
End Sub
```

The only issue that I seem to be having is that after you press the "=" button the TempSave2 variable (used to get my answer) is blank instead of having the number the user typed in. I'm unsure how to fix this I've tried rearranging pretty much it all. Any help is appreciated.

First post here so please excuse the bad layout!

Thanks, Keiran.

[image]

Excuse the awful colour scheme. My idea was if my teacher is making me learn this awful concept, he can cope with the awful colours :P

Comment: You're _just now_ learning vb6? Condolences. Control arrays aren't even part of the modern VB language any more.

Comment: Also, the `If Index = 0 Or 1 Or 2 Or 3 ...` line doesn't work the way you think it does. That's gonna do a bitwise `Or` on those integer to create a single integer value, and then compare that single value to the `index` variable.

Comment: Joel Coehoorn, Sadly this is the only environment my school teaches in :( I get that it's out dated and I've already asked to either update the environment or use a different one altogether. haha

Answer (score 3):

First, you want to check the Index value below, not the CmdCalc(Index):

```
If Index = 10 Then
    TempSave1 = LblOutput.Caption
    Symbol = "/"
ElseIf Index = 11 Then
    TempSave1 = LblOutput.Caption
    Symbol = "*"
ElseIf Index = 12 Then
    TempSave1 = LblOutput.Caption
    Symbol = "-"
ElseIf Index = 14 Then
    TempSave1 = LblOutput.Caption
    Symbol = "+"
End If
```

Next, your line:

```
If Index = 0 Or 1 Or 2 Or 3 Or 4 Or 5 Or 6 Or 7 Or 8 Or 9 Or 10 Or 11 Or 12 Or 14 Then
```

is not doing what you think it is doing.  It is evaluating all the Or statements together, then comparing that to Index.  It's as if it was written with the following parentheses:

```
If Index = (0 Or 1 Or 2 Or 3 Or 4 Or 5 Or 6 Or 7 Or 8 Or 9 Or 10 Or 11 Or 12 Or 14) Then
```

I believe that code will ONLY evaluate to true if Index = 14 but I haven't done the actual bit math, but regardless, it's clearly not what you want.

There are several ways to write this, but the shortest might be:

```
If (Index >= 0 And Index <= 12) Or Index = 14 Then
```

Without seeing the actual screen, I can't comment on the rest of the code.

Comment: The `Or` expression results in `15`. See here: http://rextester.com/HBRS42698  Link uses VB.Net, but I'd be surprised is vb6 is different for this. Personally, I'd do `If Index >=0 And Index <= 14 And Index <> 13 Then`

Comment: 1, 2, 4, and 8 - or'ed would indeed be 15.  The rest didn't matter - I blame delay in caffeine dispersal :)   Thanks for providing another example - New programmers should understand that there's (almost) always more than one "correct" answer.

Comment: I still cannot get TempSave2 to save the second number the user enters. Instead it gives me a type mismatch error. :(

Comment: You need to convert captions (strings) to doubles. `TempSave1 = CDbl(LblOutput.Caption)` or `TempSave1 = Val(LblOutput.Caption)`

Comment: Thanks! Solved now. I made my variable global instead of local so they didn't get re-wrote everytime the sub was ran.

Comment: The `Or` parens explanation is completely wrong. The first `If` evaluates to `True` for any value of `Index` (try `-1`, `42`, etc.) while the re-write evaluates to `True` only for `Index = 15` -- how come?